# Managing users in an AWS hosted application

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am brand new to AWS, but I have extensive use in C#, .Net and Visual Studio.

In previous MVC applications, I could manage access to specific pages in my application using Microsoft Identity 2.0.

What is the comparable tool in AWS? I have already installed the AWS toolkit for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Cognito is probably the closest AWS service to Microsoft Identity 2.0.

However, there is nothing stopping you from running Microsoft Identity 2.0 on AWS. I assume you're going to have a database with your application, perhaps a MSSQL Server instance on RDS, so you could just continue using Microsoft Identity 2.0 with that database. It looks like there are also third-party tools out there that let you use MS Identity 2.0 with Amazon's DynamoDB service.